# Clio API v4 returns "User is forbidden from taking that action"

Tags: clio-api

Clio API v4 returns ForbiddenError for every request. 
For example this request works without problem:

`GET /api/v2/users/who_am_i HTTP/1.1
 Host: app.clio.com
 Authorization: Bearer ***`

And this request doesn't work:

`GET /api/v4/users/who_am_i HTTP/1.1
 Host: app.clio.com
 Authorization: Bearer ***`

This is the error returned with status 403:

`{"error":{"type":"ForbiddenError","message":"User is forbidden from taking that action"}}`

The same happens with any other request.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, started after we downgraded from Elite to Boutique. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem. Here's a response from Clio, which resolved my issue.

> We have recently made a change that requires all Bulk Action requests include bearer tokens in order to be successful. If you are making requests without including bearer tokens, they will fail.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.
The problem happened because the Bearer token has been received for application registered with APIv2 and/or in wrong domain (Europe instead of USA).
That means when I approved user I approved it against wrong application.